# Spring Data Rest Content Type

Tags: spring-data-rest

I am writing unit tests for my application with Spring Data Rest MongoDB. Based on Josh's "Building REST services with Spring" get start guide, I have the following test code:

```
    @Test
    public void readSingleAccount() throws Exception {
    mockMvc.perform(get("/accounts/"
            + this.account.getId()))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andExpect(content().contentType(contentType))
            .andExpect(jsonPath("$.id", is(this.account.getId())))
                    .andExpect(jsonPath("$.email", is(this.account.getEmail())))
                    .andExpect(jsonPath("$.password", is(this.account.getPassword())));
   }
```

And this test fails on the content type.

```
Content type expected:<application/json;charset=UTF-8> but was:    <application/hal+json>
Expected :application/json;charset=UTF-8
Actual   :application/hal+json
```

I don't see [MediaType](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/MediaType.html) come with HAL. Is the content type defined in another class?

Comment: There is no point in testing the content type as it's fixed. It's set by Spring Data Rest and you want to test your application not Spring Data Rest. It would be different if the content type was variable, but it isn't, as long as you don't set it yourself.

Comment: Except it is not! If MockMvc is unable to return the correct character encoding, it will not get parsed as such and all my tests fail when actually testing the JSON produced. This renders the MockMvc completely useless and I am forced to start tomcat...

Answer (score 6):

Had the same Problem when not using tomcat (which is configured to return utf-8 using Spring Boot). The solution is to set the accept header in your GET request so the response gets the correct content type:

```
private MediaType contentType = new MediaType("application", "hal+json", Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```

and in your request, do

```
@Test
public void readSingleAccount() throws Exception {
mockMvc.perform(get("/accounts/"
        + this.account.getId()).**accept(contentType)**)
        .andExpect(status().isOk())
        .andExpect(content().contentType(contentType))
        .andExpect(jsonPath("$.id", is(this.account.getId())))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.email", is(this.account.getEmail())))
                .andExpect(jsonPath("$.password", is(this.account.getPassword())));
}
```